# how to treat * as string and not as wildcard in lucene.net

Tags: lucene.net, wildcard

I have a term **test*** and I want to treat it as string and not a wildcard of test.
How will I be able to do that in Lucene.Net. Any help???

Comment: I know in most regex situations you can escape it, like `*test*` would be `\*test\*`. Not knowing lucene.net, I'm not qualified to answer for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a backslash to escape special characters. Both in the QueryParser and custom built searches. List of characters that require escaping can be found [here](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the newer versions of Lucene.Net, you can use `QueryParser.Escape("test*")` to escape your search term. `QueryParser.Escape()` takes a string and returns the string after properly escaping all characters that are special for Lucene.